# calling jQuery inside a javaScript function, from a method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to call a jQuery inside a javaScript function, but it doesnt work, what I am doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function Test() {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#pezz").animate({
                    left: '+=150px',
                    height: '+=20px',
                    width: '+=20px'
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
```

call from a method int the Bean

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("Test");
```

UPDATE:

As Gibberish suggested I change the Script to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
   Test();
  });

 function Test() {
$("#pezz").animate({
  left: '+=150px',
  height: '+=20px',
  width: '+=20px'
});
}
</script>
```

But Works only once, Its supposed to work every time some condition is reached in the method, what canI do to fix this?

Comment: This happens because by the time your code runs, document's ready event has already fired.

Comment: Remove `document-ready` event handler

Answer (score 1):

Restructure like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    Test();
  });

  function Test() {
    $("#pezz").animate({
      left: '+=150px',
      height: '+=20px',
      width: '+=20px'
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, It works, but only one time, in the method every time the user gives the wrong answer the image move. what can I do to fix this?